# Prove $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ (the product of countably many copies of the two-point set) is uncountable.

Comment: ....$\,2^{\aleph_0}\,$ ...?

Comment: Binary numbers?

Comment: @Michael: If you're correcting the braces, why did you leave the ones after the `\mathbb`? It works perfectly well without any braces: $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Show that $\{0,1\}^A$ is the same thing as $\mathcal P(A)$; and use Cantor's theorem to show that $|A|<|\mathcal P(A)|$. Deduce the wanted conclusion.

Comment: this is a similar question to the one above: how would you  prove that the set of infinite sequences $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ that doesn't contain the continuum ${00}$ are not countable?

I was thinking that this question seems to be answered by Cantor's Diagonal by I can't think of the way to define the set  in order to defiantly have a function that won't be a in the set, in order to get a contradiction.

Comment: @Jneven: Do you know what a "base 1 representation" of a number is?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: @Jneven: It's simply counting how many "1" appear in a row. So $5$ would be $11111$ and $10$ would be $1111111111$, and so on. If you have no consecutive $00$, that means you can use $0$ as a separator as encoding of stuff in base $1$. (In fact, even if you do have $0$, you can still do that.) So your binary sequence is really a sequence of natural numbers. Just note that some sequences will have a tail of $1$s, and you need to take care of these separately. But those are countable.

Comment: @Jneven: More to the point, diagonalization does not have to *really* follow a diagonal. You just need to make sure that at some point, your information is different from a given member of the countable sequence.

Comment: @Jneven: In particular, if $f_n$ is a sequence of binary sequences with no $00$, you can define $f$ to be $1$'s only, and change the $2^n+3$th coordinate to $0$ if and only if $f_n(2^n+3)=1$. This will ensure enough space is lying between the $0$s, and still let you perform the diagonalization.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Cantor's Diagonal argument.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left|\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}\right| = \left|\{0, 1\}\right|^{|\mathbb{N}|} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \left|\mathbb{R}\right|$$

Comment: See also [Cantor's Diagonal Argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) if you haven't yet encountered it.

Comment: Do any of these answers make sense, Cornelius?